# Trouble with Etherscan API

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to connect to the Etherscan API in order download my transaction history across my cryptocurrency wallets. I've used the following Python code, which works just fine with the sample Etherscan gives in their API documentation.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

address = '0xfbb1b73c4f0bda4f67dca266ce6ef42f520fbb98' #wallet address
url = 'http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address='+address+'&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=my_api_key'

r = requests.get(url)
r.status_code #200 indicates success
json_output =r.json()
json_output["result"]
data = pd.DataFrame(json_output["result"])
```

I consistently get no data returned although the status code tells me the query is a success. Any thought? How stupid am I being?

Comment: are you using valid apikey?

Comment: @Gahan Yes. I have a login with Etherscan and my account statistics show that I have been making requests with my API key